# How do I compute the output of quantum circuit involving multiple gates?

Tags: quantum-gate, linear-algebra

I'm new in quantum computing, I have this question.

Qubits $x$ and $y$ are in $\mathbb{C}^2$ (column vector) and $A, B$ are unitary matrices ($A$ 8x8 and $B$ 4x4 matrix).

If I'm not wrong the input of $A$ is $x_1 \otimes x_2 \otimes x_3$ which is in $\mathbb{C}^8$ (column vector). Now given the output $z=A(x_1 \otimes x_2 \otimes x_3)$ how can I extract $y_3$ from $z$ to calculate $y_3 \otimes y_4$ ($x_4 = y_4$) which is the input of $B$?

[image]

Comment: Suppose the circuit goes on. I don't want to measure y's. I want to how to perform calculation after A matrix-gate.

Comment: I want to know how to calculation are peformed. I don't want to use software I want to understand the calculation.

Comment: Use the partial trace: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_trace

Comment: Thank you for your link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you cannot just extract the part of the state that corresponds to $y_3$ and $y_4$. Instead, you have to consider the entire state (which you will describe using a 16-element vector), and you apply to it the unitary $I\otimes B$ where $I$ is the $4\times 4$ identity matrix.

Comment: Thank you very much! So this is the way the calculation are made in any quantum circuit?

Comment: It's the general way that you have to perform the calculation if you want to simulate what a quantum circuit does via a classical calculation. That's the whole "problem" with quantum computation - essentially, you have to keep the whole exponentially large vector in memory, which we cannot do classically.